Divisor class group of non-reduced schemes
Let $X$ be an irreducible scheme, separated of finite type over a field. Let $i:X_{\mathrm{red}}\to X$ be the associated reduced closed subscheme. Is the Weil divisor class group (i.e., the quotient of the group of Weil divisors by the subgroup of principal divisors, defined in (11.13.5), Algebraic Geometry I: Schemes by Görtz and Wedhorn, 2nd edition) $\mathrm{Cl}(X)$ of $X$ isomorphic to $\mathrm{Cl}(X_{\mathrm{red}})$?
In https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BE4, the Weil divisor class group is defined only for integral schemes, so the question came to my mind.

What is the definition of class group in GW?

Dear @Mohan, The quotient of the group of Weil divisors by the subgroup of principal divisors.

Is the group of Weil divisors simply the abelian group generated by irreducible codimension one subvarieties? If so, it depends only the reduced scheme.

Dear @Mohan,  Yes, but the subgroup of principal divisors may be different.

I know and that would be my next question. How do they assign the cycle associated to a function? In normal varieties, the local rings at height one primes are pids and so a unique number can be assigned.
